# How to use setInterval to have Refresh on by default but off with a switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use setInterval to control a refresh of my page. I would like to have it running by default (on when the page loads) but I need to be able to turn it off at certain times. So I've written what you see below. The problem is that the refresh is not on when the page first displays. It only comes on after I click the button twice to re-activate the update the setInterval controls.

My html button definition looks like this;

```
<button id="autoref" type="button" name="autoref" onclick="stopAutoRef();">Stop Auto Ref</button>
```

My stopAutoRef function looks like this;

```
function stopAutoRef() {
    if ($("#autoref").text() == "Stop Auto Ref") {
        $("#autoref").html('Start Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is not automatically happening
        clearInterval();
    }else {$("#autoref").html('Stop Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is automatically happening
        setInterval(function() {showActivities(document.getElementById("select1").value);}, 60000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are not running setInterval(function() {showActivities(document.getElementById("select1").value);}, 60000); at document ready to initiate it the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) returns an ID which must be passed to `clearInterval` to stop it. You'd also want to call your function, `startAutoRef()`, immediately in addition to on click to initiate the default behavior of refreshing.

```
var autoRefId = null;

function stopAutoRef() {
    if (autoRefId !== null) {
        $("#autoref").html('Start Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is not automatically happening
        clearInterval(autoRefId);
        autoRefId = null;
    } else {
        $("#autoref").html('Stop Auto Ref'); // You see this if Refresh is automatically happening
        autoRefId = setInterval(function() {showActivities(document.getElementById("select1").value);}, 60000);
    }
}

stopAutoRef();
```

Comment: This worked right out of the box, turn off works and turn on works both automagically.

Answer (score 0):

clearinterval generally requires a argument of which function to stop. so try this maybe?

try this:

HTML:

```
<button id = 'b' onclick = 'stop(this)' value = 'true'>Stop ref</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var myfunc = setInterval(function(){
location.reload();
},1000);;
function stop(button){
    if(button.innerHTML == 'Stop ref'){
         button.innerHTML = 'Start ref';
        clearInterval(myfunc);
    }
    else{
        button.innerHTML = 'Stop ref';
        myfunc = setInterval(function(){
        location.reload();
        },1000);;
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to add a close bracket } at the bottom to make it work (turn it off) but when I turn it back on it does not go back to refreshing.